# What's the purpose of the Apache authentication directive AuthName?

Tags: apache, authentication

What is the purpose of the `AuthName` directive used within the `<Directory></Directory>` tag of the `httpd.conf` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AuthName` is used when using authentication with Apache. As the [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/auth.html) says:

> The [`AuthName`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#authname) directive sets the Realm to be used in the
>   authentication. The realm serves two major functions. First, the
>   client often presents this information to the user as part of the
>   password dialog box. Second, it is used by the client to determine
>   what password to send for a given authenticated area.

In the picture below (from [HeliconTech Blog](http://helicontech.wordpress.com/category/security/)), the `AuthName` has been set to "secret area".

[image: Authentication dialog]

Comment: Oh the realm name will make the user blink that he need to give particular user/passwd, because 'secret area' realm belong to protected 3 directories(say) docs, test1, test2 in webapps folder where as realm name 'Private' belong to 2 directories(say)  dummy1, dummy2 in webapps folder. Is my understanding correct? and i guess all the resources that client access must be in webapps folder of tomcat.

Comment: If yes, then as per the [link](http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/webprogramming/HTTP_Authentication.html)  i would like to understand, Can we have two <directory>s of the same realm but use different password file?

Comment: That is very easy to test, @overexchange. :-)